# subtract in sql using with remaining value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question. I got 2 tables, and wanted to create a subtraction between these tables. for example, one table is chocolate and others is total. In chocolate table, there are many values whereas in total, it is only one fixed value. So, I need to minus this total value with these chocolate price which has been paid only. I dont get the idea on how to do this. Need Help! Below is the example;

Chocolate table:

```
Item    Price    Status
----------------------
Dark     5        1
White    3        1
Normal   2        0
```

Total table:

```
Item                 Price
--------------------------
Chocolate package     $10
```

so i want the answer should be $2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database you're working on?

Comment: How the term `paid` represented in the database.Also tag the post with appropriate `RDBMS` name and version.

Comment: Also include the table structures please

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using sql..and the paid represent as status. and in status field it only has 1 or 0 value.

Comment: "SQL" is **not** a DBMS product, it's a *query language*. So which *DBMS* are you using?

Comment: phpmyadmin is a front end, not a DBMS - but as it is exclusively for the DBMS MySQL it is safe to assume that you are using that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified table structure I am assuming below

Chocolate table

```
Item    Price    Status
----------------------
Dark     5        Paid
White    3        Paid
Normal   2
```

Query

```
Select  (Select total From totalTable) - SUM(Price) as Balance
FROM ChocolateTable
WHERE Status='Paid'
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07e94/1)

Note that this query will throw error if more than one row is present in `totalTable`.